# Get a single backslash \ inside my expression in R

Tags: r, regex

In R, I wrote:

```
parse(text = "main\level") # Error
```

or

```
parse(text = "main\\level") # Error
```

or

```
parse(text = "main\\\\level") # Error
```

The result that I hope is:

```
expression(main\level)
```

How can I get my expression with a single backslash \ inside?

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I just fixed the title and the result that I hope.

Comment: Do you really need `parse`? Could you just use `expression("main\\level")`? It will print with two backslashes, but only one is there.

Comment: The result of `expression("main\\level")` is not the same as the result of  `expression(main\\level)`

Comment: Okay, the result of `expression("main\\level")` is different but can you explain why that matters?

Comment: In my case, I use expressions for communication between programming languages.